# python SQL order by number growth percentage

Tags: python, mysql

I have one table where I save all email address, and another table to save email domain and their occurrence in the first table. Everyday, there is new email added in first table and new statistic updated in second table.

This is the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE mailing (
addr VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm still working on the second table, it currently only save 2 days' statistic:

```
CREATE TABLE daily_stat(
                            domain VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                            prev_count INT,
                            cur_count INT,
                            day_count INT )
```

prev_count is occurrence of yesterday, cur_count is occurrence of today.
Everyday, the second table is updated by two function:

```
def insert(con,domain,cur_count):
try:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO daily_stat VALUES('%s' ,'%d','%d','%d' )" %(domain,0,cur_count,0))
    con.commit()
except mdb.Error, e:
    con.rollback()
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    cursor.close()

def update(con,domain, cur_count):
try:
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE daily_stat SET prev_count = cur_count,cur_count = %d, day_count = day_count+1 WHERE domain = '%s'" %(cur_count,domain))
    con.commit()
except mdb.Error, e:
    con.rollback()
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

Now I'd like to get top 50 domains which have the biggest growth percentage (increased occurrence / total row of first table) in the last 7 days.
Do I have to create 7 new columns in the second table to save number of occurrence of each day. Is there any tricky way?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us some query that you have tried so far.

Comment: did you thought about 7 day moving average? try  that.